# Connecting to remote Oracle DB using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, database, oracle, connection, cx-oracle

I am having problems connecting to a `remote Oracle DB using cx_Oracle` in my `python application`.
I have tried a lot of different ways of configuring/formulating my **connection string** based on a lot of google searching etc but I seem to get the same error message almost each time no matter what I try.

**My attempts looks like this:**

```
import cx_Oracle
ip = '[IP ADDRESS]'
port = [PORT]
service_name = '[SERVICE NAME]'
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name=service_name)
db = cx_Oracle.connect('[USERNAME]', '[PASSWORD], dsn)
```

**Result:** DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

```
import cx_Oracle
conn_str = '[USERNAME]/[PASSWORD]@[HOST IP]/[SERVICE NAME]'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)
```

**Result:** DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

```
import cx_Oracle
user= '[USERNAME]'
pwd = '[PASSWORD]'
host = '[HOST IP]' 
service_name = '[SERVICE NAME]'
portno = '[PORT]' 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user, pwd, '{}:{}/{}'.format(host,portno,service_name))
```

**Result:** DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

```
import cx_Oracle
connstr = '[USERNAME]/[PASSWORD]@[SERVICE NAME]'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
```

**Result:** DatabaseError: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I have Toad installed on my PC and have no problems what so ever connecting to the DB with that.

Any ideas what could be the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you connect in Toad - what connect string do you use?

Comment: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred means a firewall problem most of the time

Answer (score 0):

I have this standard way to connect

```
import cx_Oracle
    
host="myserver"
port=myport
sid='myservicename'
user='myuser'
password='mypassword'
sid = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name=sid)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, sid, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select 1 from dual')
```

And it works without any issue. In your case, it is quite strange that you got a timeout, which normally indicates a network problem rather than a connection issue. If you are using `cx_Oracle` version 8, you don't need to specify the encoding as UTF-8 as it is the default one.

See how it works.

```
C:\python>type testconn.py
#from __future__ import print_function  # needed for Python 2.7
import cx_Oracle
import os

host="myserver"
port=myport
sid='database_service_name'
user='myuser'
password='mypassword'
sid = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name=sid)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, sid, encoding="UTF-8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select 1 from dual')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)


C:\python>python testconn.py
(1,)

C:\python>
```

Comment: Pet peeve teminology check :) you use 'sid' as a variable to hold a 'service name'.  SIDs and Service Names are different things.